# RuntimeError:a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation

Tags: python

When I try to run the 'mobile-yolov5-pruning-distillation' project cloned from GitHub, in google colab, it got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 776, in <module>
    train(hyp)
  File "train.py", line 78, in train
    model = Model(opt.cfg).to(device)
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/project_folder/mobile-yolov5-pruning-distillation/models/yolo.py", line 73, in __init__
    self._initialize_biases()  # only run once
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/project_folder/mobile-yolov5-pruning-distillation/models/yolo.py", line 124, in _initialize_biases
    b[:, 4] += math.log(8 / (640 / s) ** 2)  # obj (8 objects per 640 image)
RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

When I try to track back to the yolo.py

```
b[:, 4] += math.log(8 / (640 / s) ** 2)  # obj (8 objects per 640 image)
```

could anyone help to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code with a torch.no_grad() `torch.no_grad(): your_code_here`
You can also use the .data attribute to update the tensor but if I understand correctly, this method is deprecated.

```
b[:, 4].data += math.log(8 / (640 / s) ** 2)  # obj (8 objects per 640 image)
```